# Unable to get FormData in express from front end server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

My express server code looks like:

```
var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })
app.post('/godam/v1/bulkUpload',upload.single('avatar'),function (request,resp) {
    var http = require("http");
    var headers = request.headers;
    var options = {
        "method": request.method,
        "hostname": apiHostUrl,
        "port": apiPort,
        "path": request.originalUrl,
        "headers": //request.headers
            {
            "content-type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW",
            "cache-control": "no-cache",
            "postman-token": "48a15104-4366-4b48-e3fd-1bf9a7f91bcf",
            "x-quikr-client": "Monetization.Api"
        }
    };

    var req = http.request(options, function (res) {
        var chunks = [];

        res.on("data", function (chunk) {
            chunks.push(chunk);
        });

        res.on("end", function () {
            var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
            console.log(body.toString());
            resp.send(body);
        });
    });

    req.write("------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"operation\"\r\n\r\nINSERT\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"type\"\r\n\r\nItr\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"files\"; filename=\"bulkupload - Sheet1.csv\"\r\nContent-Type: text/csv\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--");
    req.end();
})
```

I'm not able to get form data here to pass it in `req.write()`, 
and please let me know if multer saves data temporarily and then sends it to API? But I don't want to have this as I'm using express just as a proxy server which should just act as middleware for passing data.

My front end react server:

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('operation', "INSERT");
formData.append('type', "Itr");
formData.append('comment', "comment");
formData.append('files', "fileName");

axiosRequest({
    method: "post",
    url: "url",
    data:formData,
    headers: { 'content-type': 'multipart/form-data' }

}).then((resp) => {
}).catch((error) => {
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The server is expecting the file upload with the name `avatar` but it is not sent in the formdata from client

Comment: i tried removing but the request body remains empty, could you please suggest

Comment: check if you have bodyParser setup properly. I couldn't think anything else